# Is it possible to write attribute data to a magick object?

Tags: r, gis, exif

I have a few thousand pictures with GPS information included in metadata/exif. However the accuracy of the coordinates is sometimes poor, and I want to update these using data from a more precise GPS. Using the `magick` package I can access the coordinates, but can't figure out how to edit/write new coordinates.

```
# Taking a random geotagged pic from flickr:   
library(magick)
test <- image_read("https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/48568563581_50ea7a9d64_m.jpg?rnd=0.25039150584286607")

# looking at the attributes:
image_attributes(test)

# Can see that latitude is in:
image_attributes(test)[22,2]

# But cant edit/change them by, e.g.:*

image_attributes(tessst2)[10,2]<-c("70/1, 14/1, 6655/1000")
```